# Inserting YouTube link in modern CV

Tags: moderncv, urls

RE: Modern CV contact info - YouTube channel link

Hi,

I've tried repeatedly to include a link, in the upper-right-hand corner where my contact information is located a YouTube link to my channel, but to no avail.  I have a LinkedIn hyperlink using "\social" but cannot  seem to get the same for YouTube.  Any suggestions? I've attached a snapshot of the section but deleted the section I had for "\social[youtube]" because I kept getting errors. (I'm very new to LaTeX and am unsure how to upload the entire file otherwise).

Thanks so much!
Chris

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                            
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths} 
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\mobile{}                   
\phone{}          
\email{test@foo.bar} 
\social[linkedin]{}  

\usepackage[pdftex,
                   pdfauthor={},
                   pdftitle={CV for },
                   pdfsubject={Detailed CV for focusing on his previous training, employment and PhD research.},
                   pdfkeywords={These, are, keywords},
                   pdfproducer={ShareLaTeX},
                   pdfcreator={pdflatex},
                   pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
                   bookmarksopen,
                   pdfstartview={FitH},
                   colorlinks,
                   linkcolor={blue},
                   citecolor={red},
                   urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% EDUCATION
\section{Education}
\cventry{2012--Present}{Some education}{University}{Prescott}{Arizona}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{2008--2012}{MA (Hons)}{University}{Huntsville}{Texas}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It's hard (impossible?!) to tell from your not overly detailed description what may be going on. Please edit your posting and provide a complete MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows what you've tried so far and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Hi Mico,  I've tried to add a MWE but there is no "upload" option other than images and I'm not sure how to use some of the other options in the TeX.SE userface.  I'm relatively new to LaTeX and would appreciate your help.  If you need further information and can walk me through getting it uploaded, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: There is no need to upload the code, just copy and paste it on your question. The easiest way to make it appear as code is to select it and then click the brackets `{ }` formatting tool.

Comment: @Chris - I didn't ask for an upload of an image -- I asked you to post the LaTeX code you have (and not a screenshot of a code snippet). Still not nearly enough information to have a reasonable shot at determining what's going on. Please have a look around this site and verify for yourself that postings which provide MWEs are quite likely to get helpful and specific answers, whereas postings that provide only a generic description of a problem or two do not.

Comment: @Alvaro - thanks!  I was able to get it uploaded.  Sorry for the confusion.  I'm still very new to LaTeX and have been learning via trial/error.

Comment: @Mico - I think I got this uploaded correctly.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would suggest removing all your personal info from the MWE and making it as minimal as possible while still showing your problem

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog on the moderncv package](http://walrustech.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/moderncv-latex-package-a-really-easy-way-to-create-a-modern-cv/) there is a field called `\homepage{}` which will link to an internet page.

This gives a link to the an internet page above the social link.
In the MWE this can be added after the `\social[]{}` field

```
...
\social[linkedin]{}  
\homepage{www.youtube.com}
\usepackage{pdflatex,
...
```

Comment: @ Dolphin: Thank you for the personal info removal suggestion and the \homepage fix.  Much appreciated.